# OpenDKIM not signing outgoing mail

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, dkim, opendkim

I'm trying to setup OpenDKIM on my mailserver running Debian and Postfix. This is the configuration I've done:

- Generated two keys (for two domains I need to send mail for)
- Configured KeyTable, SigningTable and TrustedHosts files:

**KeyTable**:

```
mail._domainkey.domain1.com domain1.com:mail:/etc/opendkim/keys/domain1.com/mail.private
mail._domainkey.domain2.com domain2.com:mail:/etc/opendkim/keys/domain2.com/mail.private
```

**SigningTable**:

```
*.domain1.com mail._domainkey.domain1.com
*.domain2.com mail._domainkey.domain2.com
```

**TrustedHosts**:

```
127.0.0.1
::1
localhost
```

My `opendkim.conf` reads:

```
# This is a basic configuration that can easily be adapted to suit a standard
# installation. For more advanced options, see opendkim.conf(5) and/or
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample.

# Log to syslog
Syslog          yes
# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
UMask           002
LogWhy          yes

OversignHeaders     From

TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key

KeyTable           /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts      /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

Finally, I connected it to Postfix using the milter socket:

**Postfix main.cf**:

```
# Milters
smtpd_milters =
    unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock,
    unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl,
    unix:/spamass/spamass.sock

non_smtpd_milters = unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

In this current state, OpenDKIM does correctly verify signatures of incoming mail, but it doesn't sign outgoing mail for some reason. This is logged in `mail.log` when trying to send a message:

```
Nov  8 16:35:02 illium opendkim[30142]: 826DF501F39: %clienthostname% %clientip% not internal
Nov  8 16:35:02 illium opendkim[30142]: 826DF501F39: not authenticated
Nov  8 16:35:02 illium opendkim[30142]: 826DF501F39: no signature data
```

I believe the `not authenticated` part is incorrect, because the mail is submitted from a client to Postfix using authenticated SMTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by two things:

1. Contrary to what the comments in `opendkim.conf` claim, `mode = sv` is **not** the default. I had to set it explicitly.
2. I made an error in my SigningTable: `*.domain1.com` should be `*@domain1.com`.

After correcting these two points, it is now working correctly.

Comment: Please can you send steps you followed to setup opendkim on server, i am facing same problem emails are not signed by dkim , tried many things but failing